# Clickable links in UI Chat Application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, socket.io

I am using AngularJS in front-end and Socket.io for chat application.
When a user sends a message, Its getting rendered in UI as follows:

```
<p class="chat-msg">{{chat.msg}}</p>
```

But If user sends any link how can I make it clickable?

One approach was to pass message to a regular expression and check if it contains a link and put them in a `<a>` tag and rendering that message in above tag worked.
But If message contains some html tags which user is trying to send it across to another user, then it is getting replaced in html.
Example:

```
User1:  Show me your code in example.com  
User2:  My code is as follows : <p>This is a simple <b>app</b</p> in example.com
User3:  Looks Good
```

Here in above code only example.com should be clickable and `<p>` tag should be shown as a part of message instead of rendering it in UI.
Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should make use build-in [`linky`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky) filter (from `ngSanitize` module).

```
<p class="chat-msg" ng-bind-html="chat.msg | linky"></p>
```

However note, that `example.com` is not a linkable resource, since it must start with http/https/ftp/mailto.